# Highchart polar, align left x labels - interrupt the labels distance

Tags: css, highcharts

I use polar-highchart.

I want my x-axis labels to have text-align: left.

The problem is that when I do that, the distance of the labels is interrupted.

It start dry the label from the left side of the distance point.

I only want it to align-text to left, not take the label to other place...

Code sample:

```
xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            lineWidth: 0,
            labels: {
                distance: 35,
                style:{
                    color: 'red',
                    width: 100,
                    cursor: 'pointer',

                },
                align:'left',
                staggerLines: 1,
                events: {},
                format: this.labelFormat,

            },
        },
```

I have tried to use 'reserveSpace' property - but not helped.
See images:

**Defult align:**

[image]

**Left align:**

[image]

Comment: It will be easier for use to help you if you provide a working example of your code like on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements need to use some custom code to set those labels as you want.

Here is my idea how to achieve it:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7whqnv1s/

```
events: {
  render() {
    let chart = this,
      ticks = chart.xAxis[0].ticks;

    for (let i in ticks) {
      if (ticks[i].label.alignValue !== 'left') {
        let labelWidth = ticks[i].label.getBBox().width;

        ticks[i].label.attr({
          'text-anchor': 'left'
        })
                    //set the center label on the middle
        if (ticks[i].label.alignValue === 'center') {
          ticks[i].label.translate(-labelWidth / 2, 0)
        } else {
        //move the left labels to the left
          ticks[i].label.translate(-labelWidth, 0)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

If something is unclear - feel free to ask!

Comment: The JS work fine, how ever in my project the render event is not fired.
I tried to add this logic at load event in after timeOut of 100 ms, but ticks[i].label ave no property called alignValue . What can be the reasons?

Comment: I found that this is because I use version 4.1.8, Is there any solution for this version?

Comment: I have noticed that in the version which you are using this behaviour happens by default when the useHTML is set to true. See: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z7xbv1f4/